# jQuery syntax error for a valid json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get the instagram user details using jQuery ajax which can be found from the url

```
https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
```

But when i call the same through ajax from my following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var instagram = 'instagram';
    $.ajax({
      url : 'https://www.instagram.com/'+ instagram +'/?__a=1',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(e) {
        document.write(JSON.stringify(e));
      }
    });
});
```

It is returning me a error :

> missing ; before statement  [In Json]

However when i copy and paste it for validation on some online tools available it is showing valid formatted json.

> DEMO : https://codepen.io/abhibagul/pen/WXGoYb?editors=0010
>
> Error is visible in the browser console.

Comment: did you tried with `dataType: 'application/json' instead of `jsonp`?

Comment: @FeMachine `json` will not work, it will require `jsonp` as of Same Origin Policy.

Comment: at bottom of https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ you can see that you should ask for a callback and there's how the response should look like, did you tried that? here's a simple explained guide with examples.. https://rudrastyh.com/javascript/get-photos-from-instagram.html

Comment: @user123456789 Well JSONP will not work when the API returns JSON. If it does not support JSONP, you cannot use it. That's what the SOP is made to protect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting respone as `JSON`,
Change from `dataType: "jsonp"` to `dataType: "json"`

Valide json response would look like

```
{
     "Name": "Foo",
     "Id": 192.168.73.96,
     "Rank": 7
}
```

And jsonp would be like

```
parseResponse({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});
```

Get more details form [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: `jsonp` is just ment to access the data from cross origins. `json` will not work here.

Comment: @user123456789 : ensure that you have proper response as second example

Answer (score 0):

Instagram does not support jsonp, it is not used much anymore in favor of CORS. Change `jsonp` to `json`. However, this will not work because Instagram's CORS policy prevents it. You will need to use the API provided by Instagram.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var instagram = 'instagram';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.instagram.com/' + instagram + '/?__a=1',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(e) {
      document.write(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```